# JToolbar is not resizing with JDesktopPane in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jdesktoppane, jtoolbar

I am trying to add a JToolbar to a JDesktopPane in Netbeans.  However, when I add the JToolbar to the JDesktopPane, and I maximize the JDesktopPane on runtime, the JToolbar remains the same size. JToolbar is not resizing along with the other components.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add ComponentListener to the `JDesktopPane`:

```
jDesktopPane1.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
@Override
     public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
         Dimension desktopSize = jDesktopPane1.getSize();
         int dWidth = (int) desktopSize.getWidth();
         int dHeight = (int) desktopSize.getHeight();

         jToolBar1.setSize(dWidth, jToolBar1.getHeight());
     }
}
```